# Getting an error message trying to install better sqlite3 on rpi4

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, better-sqlite3

I was trying to install better-sqlite3 again when I found out the package was missing when i ran npm update, here is the error message (RPI4b 4gb, Running Raspbian) . Also I a, using a couple other packages that require this as a dependancy. I am using an unofficial release of nodejs 15.10 because thats how i can run discord.js 12

```
    npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/pi/OG Bot/node_modules/better-sqlite3
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c prebuild-install || npm run build-release
npm ERR! > better-sqlite3@7.1.2 build-release
npm ERR! > node-gyp rebuild --release
npm ERR!
npm ERR! make: Entering directory '/home/pi/OG Bot/node_modules/better-sqlite3/build'
npm ERR!   TOUCH b857c92884e9598d609f6be182a2595df7a8e00f.intermediate
npm ERR!   ACTION deps_sqlite3_gyp_locate_sqlite3_target_extract_sqlite3 b857c92884e9598d609f6be182a2595df7a8e00f.intermediate
npm ERR! rm b857c92884e9598d609f6be182a2595df7a8e00f.intermediate
npm ERR! make: Leaving directory '/home/pi/OG Bot/node_modules/better-sqlite3/build'
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp info using node@15.10.0 | linux | arm
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.7.3 found at "/usr/bin/python3"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python3
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/pi/OG Bot/node_modules/better-sqlite3/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/pi/.cache/node-gyp/15.10.0/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/home/pi/.cache/node-gyp/15.10.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/home/pi/.cache/node-gyp/15.10.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/home/pi/OG Bot/node_modules/better-sqlite3',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp info spawn make
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
npm ERR! /bin/sh: 1: Bot/node_modules/better-sqlite3/build/Release/lib.host:/home/pi/OG: not found
npm ERR! /home/pi/OG Bot/node_modules/better-sqlite3/deps/extract.js:8
npm ERR! process.on('unhandledRejection', (err) => { throw err; });
npm ERR!                                             ^
npm ERR!
npm ERR! CwdError: ENOENT: Cannot cd into '/home/pi/OG Bot/node_modules/better-sqlite3/build/Release/obj/gen/sqlite3'
npm ERR!     at /home/pi/OG Bot/node_modules/tar/lib/mkdir.js:74:14
npm ERR!     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:196:21) {
npm ERR!   path: '/home/pi/OG Bot/node_modules/better-sqlite3/build/Release/obj/gen/sqlite3',
npm ERR!   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! make: *** [deps/locate_sqlite3.target.mk:17: b857c92884e9598d609f6be182a2595df7a8e00f.intermediate] Error 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:378:20)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 5.10.11-v7l+
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--release"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /home/pi/OG Bot/node_modules/better-sqlite3
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v15.10.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/pi/.npm/_logs/2021-02-28T16_44_16_180Z-debug.log
```

Comment: It looks like one of the build scripts for a package isn't dealing with the space in your directory name (`OG BOT`) - have you tried with a directory that does not have spaces?

Comment: No I have not. Thanks I will try this!